# Update trigger causing the column of destination table to set to zero

Tags: mysql

Update trigger is causing the column of destination table to set to zero
Here is the code

```
CREATE TRIGGER `inventory-company-update-trigger` AFTER UPDATE ON `db_company`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    UPDATE inventory_companies 
    SET name = NEW.dc_name 
    AND updated_at = NOW() 
    WHERE name = OLD.dc_name;
END
```

Comment: Can you add your table definitions, sample data and the update to db_company that is causing the problem.

Comment: SET name = NEW.dc_name AND updated_at = NOW() WHERE name = OLD.dc_name; - looks suspect what are you trying to do here? if you are trying to set updated at the statement should be SET name = NEW.dc_name, updated_at = NOW() WHERE name = OLD.dc_name;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using  `SET name = NEW.dc_name AND updated_at = NOW()`

the code `NEW.dc_name AND updated_at = NOW()`  is evaluated  and if fails the result is 0

could be you just want update the two column  `name` and `updated_at`  eg:

```
UPDATE inventory_companies 
SET name = NEW.dc_name 
  , updated_at = NOW() 
 WHERE name = OLD.dc_name;
```